# How can I clean up database changes made in django-nose test functions?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, postgresql, django-nose

We write our test suite using nose function tests for a variety of reasons.

When running the test suite for our Django application, we would like to avoid leaking any data out of these tests (as with `django.test.TestCase`), because that leads to coupling and hard to diagnose failures.

The most obvious means of solving this is a decorator which we can just wrap around tests that we want to be cleaned-up after, but I'm not married to that if a different solution can get us what we want.

We run on PostgreSQL, so Postgres-specific solutions would be fine.

Comment: django automatically tears down database for each test run, this creates an isolated test environment

Comment: @dm03514 After poking around for a bit, I've realised that this is happening with django-nose test functions, not the more general case that I'd originally drafted the question with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've spent a bit of time looking at this today, and have come up with the following decorator:

```
from functools import wraps

from django.db import transaction
from mock import patch

def rollback_db_changes(func):
    """Decorate a function so that it will be rolled back once completed."""
    @wraps(func)
    @transaction.commit_manually
    def new_f(*args, **kwargs):
        def fake_commit(using=None):
            # Don't properly commit the transaction, so we can roll it back
            transaction.set_clean(using)
        patcher = patch('django.db.transaction.commit', fake_commit)
        patcher.start()
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        finally:
            patcher.stop()
            transaction.rollback()
    return new_f
```

We perform the patching so that the Django test client doesn't close the transaction without us being able to roll it back.  This allows the following tests to pass:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

@rollback_db_changes
def test_allowed_access():
    user = User.objects.create(username='test_user')
    eq_(1, User.objects.count())


@rollback_db_changes
def test_allowed_access_2():
    user = User.objects.create(username='test_user')
    eq_(1, User.objects.count())
```

Previously the second test to run could not create a user with a duplicated user name.

Comment: Well, strictly speaking those tests fail because other places in our codebase aren't cleaning up their mess.  But you get the point.